# XSLT Transformer ThrowsException : Cannot write more than one result document to the same URI

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

We have small data migration Job. In that, We are outputting into XML and then Applying Transformation using XSLT2.0.

**Scenario**

But,When we added one sub-element into OrderHeader of XML.
that is OrderLineID. Then,It is not writing multiple file of Expected Order.

For Ex:
It should  write Multiple file after XSLT.

SORTOIDOC_ORD-411323

SORTOIDOC_ORD-411324
SORTOIDOC_ORD-411325

It is throwing following error:

```
Error at xsl:result-document on line 15 of so4.xsl:
XTDE1490: Cannot write more than one result document to the same URI:
file:/C:/Data/dir/SORTOIDOC_ORD-411324.xml
Exception in component tXSLT_1
SystemID: file:/C:/Software/TOS_BD-20150908_1633-V6.0.1/workspace/xmlout/so4.xsl; Line#: 15; Column#: -1
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Cannot write more than one result document to the same URI: file:/C:/Data/dir/SORTOIDOC_ORD-411324.xml
```

Output XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<SalesOrders xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SORTOIDOC.XSD">
   <Orders>
      <OrderHeader>
         <CustomerPoNumber>Manual Order 3</CustomerPoNumber>
      <SalesForceOrderNumber>ORD-411325</SalesForceOrderNumber>
         <OrderLineID>OR-1561180</OrderLineID>
      </OrderHeader>
      <OrderDetails>
         <StockLine>
            <CustomerPoLine>9999</CustomerPoLine>
            <LineCancelCode/>
            <StockCode>ACSH-NHH-12OZ-12</StockCode>
            <StockDescription>NHH ABYSS CHIA SHAMPOO 12OZ CS</StockDescription>
            <Warehouse/>
            <CustomersPartNumber/>
        </StockLine>
      </OrderDetails>
   </Orders>
</SalesOrders>
```

XSLT 2.O IS Look like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="Windows-1252" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@xsi:nil[.='true']" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="SalesOrders/Orders" group-by="OrderHeader">
        <xsl:result-document href="SORTOIDOC_{OrderHeader/SalesForceOrderNumber}.xml">
            <SalesOrders xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SORTOIDOC.XSD">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </SalesOrders>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

**Why:**

Just adding element into XML OUTPUT Model causes problem  in writing multiple file of XML and their line items. Rather before adding this (OrderLineID) WHOLE scenario works as Expected.

Any help on it would be much Appreciated ?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: So which element do you want to group on? `<xsl:for-each-group select="SalesOrders/Orders" group-by="OrderHeader">` would group on the string value of the `OrderHeader` element which has various child elements, that at least sounds odd or might result in more groups as you want.

Comment: I would like to result  in more groups.

Comment: Consider to post a small but complete input XML for which you get the error you have shown. If you want the result document to have the `OrderHeader/SalesForceOrderNumber` in each file name, are you sure you don't want to group on that value as well with e.g. `<xsl:for-each-group select="SalesOrders/Orders" group-by="OrderHeader/SalesForceOrderNumber">`?

Comment: Let me  try and check on production environment. i will get back within few minutes.

Comment: Thanks. It is  working for me and started writing as expected result that is multiple XML Output File.

Comment: I have put the suggestion into an answer so that you can accept it and mark the question as solved.

Comment: Ok i have marked  it as answer. Thanks a ton !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if you want to group on `OrderHeader/SalesForceOrderNumber` and not on `OrderHeader` so you can change the template to

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="SalesOrders/Orders" group-by="OrderHeader/SalesForceOrderNumber">
        <xsl:result-document href="SORTOIDOC_{current-grouping-key()}.xml">
            <SalesOrders xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsd:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="SORTOIDOC.XSD">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </SalesOrders>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```